# Correctly hosting Jekyll website on Git Pages

Tags: deployment, github, web, jekyll

I am desperate.My mission is to deploy a static website generated using [Jekyll](http://jekyllrb.com/) into [GitHub Pages](http://pages.github.com/), using the "Project" option (instead of the user option).

Somehow, when I use Jekyll to check the website in my machine, everything works fine. But once I deploy it to Git Pages, all my CSS files stop working, and every link leads to a 404 not found error.

I have followed several guides and tutorials but they all fail:

- [Using Github Pages to host a website v2](http://www.youtube.com/watch?annotation_id=annotation_316685&feature=iv&src_vid=6A4AGCPbuJw&v=bNVU82qP1n4)
- [Jekyll Documentation](http://jekyllrb.com/docs/github-pages/)
- [Building Static Sites with Jekyll](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/other/building-static-sites-with-jekyll/?search_index=1)
- [building-a-docs-site-with-jekyll-github-pages](http://blog.jetstrap.com/2013/03/building-a-docs-site-with-jekyll-github-pages/)

So far I always created the repositories, the branches and I always push everything. I do not believe the error is in the deployment, but in some place else.

My repo can be found here:

- [Fl4m3Ph03n1x web-tutorials repo](https://github.com/Fl4m3Ph03n1x/web-tutorials)

For those of you wondering, so far the repository is only the result of one tutorial:
 - [AndrewMunssel tutorial](http://www.andrewmunsell.com/tutorials/jekyll-by-example/)

I have also tested other tutorials, but I always end up with a problem. Is my code wrong? Are the tutorials I am following outdated and incorrect? What should I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Everything on your site is in a sub directory off of the domain so the main site is accessed here

`http://fl4m3ph03n1x.github.io/web-tutorials/`

The templates are pointing to directories on the root of the domain so it is trying to load your stylesheets from `http://fl4m3ph03n1x.github.io/assets` rather than where they are located `http://fl4m3ph03n1x.github.io/web-tutorials/assets/` the same thing is happening for your posts.

What you need to do is set the `baseurl` in your `_config.yml`

```
baseurl: /web-tutorials
```

you then need to modify your templates so that the paths to CSS and JS use the following convention

```
{{ site.baseurl }}/path/to/css.css
```

and for post links

```
{{ site.baseurl }}{{ post.url }}
```

You also need to update the `site` setting in `_config.yml`

Comment: You mean "Site Source" or "Site Destination"? I cannot find a variable "site" here: http://jekyllrb.com/docs/configuration/

Comment: Also, by making those changes it appears that I loose the ability to locally test the website using `jekyll serve --watch`. Is there a way to avoid this?

Comment: I figured out a way to develop in my local machine. All I have to do is to manually set `baseurl: /`. Then, before I push it to Git Pages, I update that property to `baseurl: /projectName/` and I push the project. Thanks for the help and tips! I still do not understand your suggestion about the _config-yml file though.

Comment: sorry meant `url` in `_config.yml`

Comment: Should I change it to `url: /we-tutorials` as well?

Comment: Try changing it to `url: "http://fl4m3ph03n1x.github.io"`. This is only for the `_config.yml` on GitHub, your local copy should be changed.