# Jekyll on Github on Jekyll

Tags: github, deployment, jekyll

This must be a simple question but I am at a loss. I am new to web technologies but am trying to create a blog using Jekyll and host it on Github. It looks great locally but when I push it to Github I can't get it to load and I just get 404s.

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18257630/correctly-hosting-jekyll-website-on-git-pages) similar question on SO and followed the accepted answer but this did not work for me. This is my [repo](https://github.com/G-Thomson/The_Mindfield). How can I get my website to display?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Everything seems to be ok now. At first commit, you need to wait a little for your static pages to be created.

Comment: I suggest you to give a look at this [article](http://virtuacreative.github.io/blog/free-hosting-website-github.html), where I explain exactly how to publish your website on GitHub. After that, you might want to upload your Jekyll website via [GitHub Desktop](https://desktop.github.com/), as it is easier than via command line. Don't forget to add a gemfile. Have you manage to see your Jekyll website on your local machine?

Answer (score 0):

You need to push to the `gh-pages` branch to tell GitHub Pages to serve your site.

See the [documentation](https://pages.github.com/).

Comment: From the documentation I was under the impression that as a user or organization site I could just push it to master. Reading the docs more closely I see the name of the repo has to be in the form username.github.io. This seems to work although its not running CSS. but thats another issue

Comment: You're right, G_T. The key is the repo name (username.github.io) and it also need to be a public repository. In order to have your CSS working, make sure you have full urls all over the website. For example, instead of `href="/css/styles.css"`, you should try `href="http://username.github.io/css/styles.css"`. Do that for images too. This way you should be fine. Hope to have helped.

Comment: @VirtuaCreative: No; just use relative paths.

Comment: Hi @Slaks. Why do you say "no"? When I first started using Jekyll I did as you said, using just relative paths. Then, when I uploaded the website to GitHub, most of links were broken. So I had to use full paths. That's why I recommend it...

Comment: @VirtuaCreative: That should not happen (except for Jekyll transforms). What paths were you using? Were you publishing to a domain root or a project subpage? Hard-coding your own domain name in URLs is poor practice.

Comment: I meant I need to use full paths for all images and some links. Like `{{ site.baseurl }}/img/image.png`. If I don't, the image doesn't display. Not for anchors, which I can use just `#anchor`. Just in case I use `{{ site.baseurl }}` for the rest. Oh, and I use both user websites and project websites. Doesn't matter, most links break if I don't use full paths.